# Page curl effect for pdf vfr reader

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I'm currently in the middle of a PDF eBook reading application. i've chosen https://github.com/vfr/Reader as the PDF reader. everything is perfect but I need to add one extra functionality .

Page curl effect when pdf is slide to left and right

Help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the page curl effect by using a [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/).

Comment: yea I know . but I could not find where to change in that "Reader" lib to get the curling effect working. thats why I was looking for some help :/

Comment: You might want to file an issue with that library to see if you can get help from the author/maintainer.